# How to make the auto-complete information more compact in emacs-jedi?

Tags: python, emacs, jedi

I have been learning python about a month and I used emacs24.3 with jedi to write python code.
The jedi works very well, I like it very much. However, I would like to make the auto-complete menu more compact:
[image]
We can see that the auto-complete information has some redundance and hide the doc information due to the auto-complete menu is too long.
Instead of:

```
array                          Import: from numpy.core.numeric import array i
array_str                                       Function: numeric.array_str f
array_type Statement: array_type = [{balabalabalaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx }] s
```

I want something like this:

```
array               numpy.core.numeric i
array_str            numeric.array_str f
array_type              [{xxxxxx... }] s
```

And here is the auto-complete pop menu of PyCharm for comparison.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pull request for popup.el (emacs-jedi depends on auto-complete.el and auto-complete.el depends on popup.el) to fix this problem:
https://github.com/auto-complete/popup-el/pull/28

You might want to watch this pull request.  The review process is nearly finished.

For meanwhile, if you don't want to hide popup documentation, you can use pos-tip.el (http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/pos-tip.el)

---

Edit:

I think making summary information more compact is a good suggestion.  Why not post a feature request in Jedi's issue tracker: https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi

Comment: Since I think this request should be common, I'm not sure if this function already existed in somewhere.